# Writing data from AWS RDS SQL Server to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

According to this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/User.SQLServer.Options.S3-integration.html we should be able to write a file from RDS to S3. But when we try it fails with

`blocked because RDS is a managed service with SLA and guard rails to help deliver it.`

Anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like running your task will interfere with SLA's, so it would be directly related to the Note mentioned in the link you shared:

> Note: S3 integration tasks share the same queue as native backup and
> restore tasks. At maximum, you can have only two tasks in progress at
> any time in this queue. Therefore, two running native backup and
> restore tasks will block any S3 integration tasks.

There must be some automated backup activity going on when you run your task.